# removing multiple instances of a string in a line with sed

Tags: csv, unix, sed, replace

I have a large tab delimited file that I'd like keep only a certain string (GO:#######) that appears multiple (and variable) times in each line as well as lines that are blank containing a period.  When I use SED to replace all the non-GO strings it removes the entire middle of the line.  How do I prevent this?

SED command I'm using and other permutations

```
sed -r 's/\t`.+`\t//g' file1.txt > file2.txt
```

What I have

```
GO:1234567    `text1`moretext`    GO:5373845    `diff`text`     GO:5438534     `text`text
.
GO:3333333     `txt`text`    GO:5553535    `misc`text
.
.
```

What I'd like

```
GO:1234567    GO:5373845    GO:5438534
.
GO:3333333    GO:5553535
.
.
```

What I get

```
GO:1234567    GO:5438534     `text`text
.
GO:3333333    GO:5553535    `misc`text
.
.
```

Comment: That is extremely odd, the output of your code should have been `GO:1234567 GO:5438534 text`. I can't reproduce your output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sed -E 's/\t`[^\t]*//g'
```

- `\t`- tab
- `` ` `` - a literal backtick
- `[^\t]*` - any non-tab character 0 or more times

---

Alternative:

```
sed -E 's/\t(`[^`]*){2}`?//g'
```

- `\t` - tab
- `(` - start of group

  - `` ` `` - a literal backtick
  - `` [^`]* `` - any non-backticks 0 or more times
- `)` - end of group
- `{2}` - repeat group twice
- `` `? `` - an optional backtick (since the last column only has 2 instead of 3)

---

... and substitute with an empty string.

Output:

```
GO:1234567      GO:5373845      GO:5438534
.
GO:3333333      GO:5553535
.
.
```

Note: These examples assumes that there is exactly *one* <kbd>tab</kbd> between columns. It's hard to see here.

Comment: Thank you.  This works wonderfully.  The [^`] is new to me.

Comment: If a line has `abc GO:3333333` then this won't work.

Comment: @anubhava Well, it makes no substitution between those columns, that's true. Perhaps I shouldn't have let OPs original expression influence me but instead read the _"I'd like keep only a certain string (GO:#######)"_ instruction. :-)

Comment: When you want to support a backquote field at the beginning of the line and a `GO` field at the end (not required in the current question), you can use `sed -r 's/(\t|^)`[^\t]+(\t|$)/==\t/g'`

Answer (score 3):

With GNU `awk`:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FPAT="GO:[0-9]+"; OFS="\t"} {$1=$1; print}' file
```

Output is tab delimited:

```
GO:1234567  GO:5373845  GO:5438534

GO:3333333  GO:5553535
```

From `man awk`:

> **FPAT**:        A regular expression describing the contents of the fields in a record.  When set, gawk parses the  in‐
> put into fields, where the fields match the regular expression, instead of using the value of FS as the
> field separator.

See: [8 Powerful Awk Built-in Variables – FS, **OFS**, RS, ORS, NR, NF, FILENAME, FNR](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/01/8-powerful-awk-built-in-variables-fs-ofs-rs-ors-nr-nf-filename-fnr/)

Comment: This removes the periods from empty lines when used by me, otherwise it works great.

Answer (score 2):

This `awk` solution would work with any version of `awk`:

```bash
awk '
BEGIN {
   FS=OFS="\t"
}
{
   for (i=1; i<=NF; ++i)
      if ($i ~ /^GO:/)
         s = (s ? s OFS : "") $i
   print s
   s = ""
}' file

GO:1234567  GO:5373845  GO:5438534
GO:3333333  GO:5553535
GO:3333333
```

Answer (score 0):

I would match explicitly non `.

```
s/`[^`]*`[^`]*`//
```

Regex is greedy, `` `.+` `` matches *anything*, from the *first* backtick up to the *last* backtick.

Comment: I understand it's tendencies, just wasn't sure how to get around it.

Comment: The last field of the input is missing the end-backtic.

Answer (score 0):

This pattern `` \t`.+`\t `` matches from a tab followed by `` ` `` till the last occurrence of that same pattern, which matches too much.

There don't seem to be any spaces in the parts that start with a backtick that you want to remove.

I think awk is better suited for this task, but in that case with `sed` you can remove all strings that start with a backtick `` ` `` followed by non whitespace characters.

If you remove multiple consecutive fields, or a field at the start or end, there can occur gaps with multiple tabs that you can also replace with an empty string.

```
sed -E 's/(\t|^)`[^[:space:]]*//g;s/^\t+|\t+$|//g;s/\t{2,}/\t/g' file
```

The tab delimited content of *file*

```
GO:1234567  `text1`moretext`    GO:5373845  `diff`text` GO:5438534  `text`text
.
GO:3333333  `txt`text`  GO:5553535  `misc`text
..
`txt`text`  GO:3333333  `txt`text`  `txt`text`  `txt`text`  GO:5553535  `misc`text  `misc`text
```

Output

```
GO:1234567      GO:5373845      GO:5438534
.
GO:3333333      GO:5553535
..
GO:3333333      GO:5553535
```